# Python 3; tkinter keypress events won't work

Tags: python, tkinter

When this code is run, it shows a tkinter screen with 3 blue circles at the bottom of the screen. I am trying to make it so when a key button is pressed, the two circles turn white for a second before returning back to blue.

Here's the original code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=800, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                   bg="black")
canvas.grid()

def _create_circle(self, x, y, r, **kwargs): #function for drawing circles
    return self.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, **kwargs)
tk.Canvas.create_circle = _create_circle



def game():
    global color
    color = 'blue'
    root.title("Circles and Arcs")
    
    
    canvas.create_circle(100, 700, 50, fill=color, outline="#DDD", width=4) # |-|
    canvas.create_circle(300, 700, 50, fill=color, outline="#DDD", width=4)#  |  }  for the 4 circles at
    canvas.create_circle(500, 700, 50, fill=color, outline="#DDD", width=4) # |  }   the hit line
    canvas.create_circle(700, 700, 50, fill=color, outline="#DDD", width=4) # |_|

    root.mainloop()



game()
```

I've added a `root.bind('d', press_d)` thing, and made press_d a function. This function controls the variable `color`.

Here's the code with my non-working attempt.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=800, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                   bg="black")
canvas.grid()

def _create_circle(self, x, y, r, **kwargs): #function for drawing circles
    return self.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, **kwargs)
tk.Canvas.create_circle = _create_circle


def press_d(event = ' '):
    global color
    print('d is pressed')
    color = 'red'
    
    return color



def game():
    global color
    global color
    color = 'blue'
    root.title("Circles and Arcs")
    
    
    canvas.create_circle(100, 700, 50, fill=color, outline="#DDD", width=4) # |-|
    canvas.create_circle(300, 700, 50, fill=color, outline="#DDD", width=4)#  |  }  for the 4 circles at
    canvas.create_circle(500, 700, 50, fill=color, outline="#DDD", width=4) # |  }   the hit line
    canvas.create_circle(700, 700, 50, fill=color, outline="#DDD", width=4) # |_|

    root.mainloop()



game()
```

In theory, my understanding is when 'd' is pressed, it runs `press_d` function. This function has a global var called color, and the color changes to red. It then returns the color. When color is called in the `game()` function, color should be red.

However this doesn't work. It doesn't spit any errors. It just doesn't work. The function never gets called when I press d. the `print('d is pressed')` statement never shows.

Any tips or advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: there is no `color` outside the functions. You have to define it there as well.

Comment: @RolandSmith i set color as a global variable shouldn't that make work outside of functions

Comment: No. the `global` statement is only a directive to the parser. See the Python language definition in the documentation.

Comment: how do u reckon i make the color var change across functions? I tried returning in in def press_d but that doesn't do nothing.

Comment: Using `global` is fine. You just have to define `color` somewhere in the file outside of the functions.